# Como pasar dos valores nulos al JSON de un POST

Tags: typescript, spring, vscode

Con mis compañeros de proyecto final nos encontramos en un problema. Tenemos una clase usuario que contiene los siguientes atributos:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idUsuario;


@Column(unique = true)
private String nombreUsuario;

@NotNull
@Column
private String apellidoUsuario;

@NotNull
@Column
private String email;

@NotNull
@Column
private String nombrePila;

@NotNull
@Column
private String contra;


@Column
private String telefonoUsuario;

@Column
private String posicion;
```

Estos dos ultimos atributos corresponden al registro del usuario desde el modulo mobile (Posee un rol Jugador). Lo que queremos hacer es lo siguiente:
En la web tenemos un formulario ya hecho para generar usuarios, pero no nos hace falta pasarle ni el telefono ni la posicion ( en la BD quedarán en null ambos atributos, ya que solamente deben estar disponibles cuando el registro se haga desde la app mobile)

*Como hacemos para que en el JSON nos envíe todos los datos, inclusive estos dos pero en null?.
Adjunto codigo front-End del formulario y capturas del mismo.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel:wght@700;800&family=Do+Hyeon&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nuevo-usuario.component.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,500;1,400&family=Scheherazade:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<header>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="tranparente col-md-7">
        
        <form class="form-register shadow p-4 mb-4 mt-4" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="guardar(formulario)"
          #formulario="ngForm">
          <h1 class="titulo text-center"><b>Nuevo Usuario</b></h1>
          <hr style="border-color:#333736;">
          <label class="label" for="nombreUsuario">Nombre de Usuario:</label>
          <input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" ngModel name="nombreUsuario"
            id="nombreUsuario" placeholder="Ingrese nombre de usuario" required #nombreUsuario="ngModel"
            [class.is-invalid]="nombreUsuario.invalid && nombreUsuario.touched"
            [class.is-valid]="nombreUsuario.valid" minlength="7"
            title="El usuario debe contener como minimo 7 letras">

          <label class="label" for="contra">Contraseña:</label>
          <input class="form-control mb-2" type="password" ngModel name="contra" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña"
            pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{7,16}" required #contra="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="contra.invalid && contra.touched"
            [class.is-valid]="contra.valid" minlength="7" maxlength="16"
            title="Letras y números. Tamaño mínimo: 7. Tamaño máximo: 16">

          <label class="label" for="nombrePila">Nombre:</label>
          <input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" ngModel name="nombrePila" placeholder="Ingrese nombre"
            required #nombrePila="ngModel"
            [class.is-invalid]="nombrePila.invalid && nombrePila.touched"
            [class.is-valid]="nombrePila.valid" minlength="3">

          <label class="label" for="apellidoUsuario">Apellido:</label>
          <input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" ngModel name="apellidoUsuario" id="apellido"
            placeholder="Ingrese apellido" required #apellidoUsuario="ngModel"
            [class.is-invalid]="apellidoUsuario.invalid && apellidoUsuario.touched"
            [class.is-valid]="apellidoUsuario.valid" minlength="3">

          <label class="label" for="email">E-mail:</label>
          <input class="form-control mb-2" type="email" ngModel name="email" placeholder="Ingrese e-mail"
            pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}" required
            #email="ngModel"
            [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched"
            [class.is-valid]="email.valid">
          
          

          <!-- <input  type="checkbox" ngModel name="roles" id="idRol" required >
            <label *ngFor="let r of roles" [ngValue]="[r.idRol]" for="roles">{{User}}</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="2">
            <label for="vehicle2">ADMIN</label><br> -->


          <label class="label">Rol:</label>
          <select class="form-control mb-4" ngModel name="roles" id="idRol" required #rol="ngModel"
          [class.is-invalid]="rol.invalid && rol.touched"
          [class.is-valid]="rol.valid">
            <option selected="true">Seleccione un rol</option>
            <option *ngFor="let r of roles" [ngValue]="[r.idRol]">{{r.rolNombre}}</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Registrar </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/index"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
            Volver </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Nuevo-usuario.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuarioService, Usuario } from 'src/app/service/usuario.service';
import { TokenService } from 'src/app/service/token.service';
import { RolesService, Rol } from 'src/app/service/roles.service';

import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { THIS_EXPR } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nuevo-usuario',
  templateUrl: './nuevo-usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nuevo-usuario.component.css']
})
export class NuevoUsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
  roles: Rol[];
  rolSeleccionado:Rol;
  usuarios:Usuario;
  
  constructor(
    private _servicio: UsuarioService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router,
    private servicioRol : RolesService) { 
      this.roles = [
        {idRol: 1, rolNombre: "Admin"},
        {idRol: 2, rolNombre: "User"}
      ]
    }
    
    

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.servicioRol.get().subscribe(respuesta => {this.roles = respuesta;})
  }


  guardar(miFormulario) {
    if (miFormulario.valid) {
      this._servicio.guardarUsuario(miFormulario.value).subscribe(respuesta => {
        this.toastr.success('Usuario Creado', 'OK', { timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-center' });
        this.router.navigate(['/index']);
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error(err.error.mensaje, 'ERROR', { timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-center' });
        
      },
    )}
    
  }
```

**usuario.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UrlService } from './url.service';
import { Rol } from './roles.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuarioService {
private usuarios: Usuario[] = [];
  constructor(private _http : HttpClient , private _url : UrlService ) { }

  get(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get<Usuario[]>(this._url.getURLBase() + '/auth/usuarios');
  }

  guardarUsuario(Usuario: any): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(this._url.getURLBase() + '/auth/nuevo', Usuario);
  }


}

export interface Usuario{
  idUsuario:number;
  apellidoUsuario: string;
  contra:string;
  email: string;
  nombrePila : string;
  nombreUsuario: string;
  posicion:string;
  telefonoUsuario:string;
  roles: Set<Rol>;
}
```

[image: Este es el POST que me hace, no me lo acepta porque me faltan los ultimos dos atributos, seteados en nul]

Comment: Solo un detalle, las etiquetas suelen hacer referencia a las tecnologías con las que tienes dudas, no al IDE con el que trabajas y que, en este caso, no tiene absolutamente nada que ver. Te recomiendo que añadas las etiquetas adecuadas a la pregunta para que la persona correcta pueda encontrarla. Por otro lado, qué has intentado para enviar lo valores? El html está bien ponerlo, pero imagino que hará falta ver también el javascript encargado de tratar ese formulario?

Comment: Ahi cambie la prublicacion, creo que ahora esta mas completa y con las etiquetas correctas, si puedes hecharle un vistazo y me avisas! gracias por la ayuda